# Browser does not show changes in JavaScript. It keeps the old version

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, browser

Im working with:

- Chrome
- Codegnitor (PHP)
- XAMPP
- CSS and JS

My problem is:
When I do a small change in CSS or JS (any simple, trivial change), the browser does not show this change. Only when I rename the CSS or JS file it shows the change.

Its looks like the browser remembers the old version of CSS or JS and does not "go and look for the changes" when I reload the page in Chrome.

Any idea what is holding back the browser?

I've been searching for a question, but found only people whose browsers do not take jS into consideration at all.

But my browser does. It deos load JS, but not the changes that I make.

The funny thing is that a week ago I needed to rename CSS and JS file once or twice a day, but now I need to rename it when I make any change to see that change displayed in the browser.

So it is imposible to work.

Someone having the same issue?

P.S. I'm having the same issue with Mozilla nad IE. So I guess somthing could be wrong with my computer. Could it be one of those security programs. I've got one with FileZilla two  weeks ago but I thought I've got rid of it. Maybe it is still making the mess in the background.

Comment: It's caching it. Best thing to do is work in incognito so it is forced to refresh it.

Comment: Clear the cache! Usually you can press CTRL + F5 to reload the whole page and all the scripts, etc. from new.

Comment: Chrome is notorious for caching. One advice is to try your code in Incognito mode.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried Incognito and it workd. Good trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS and js resources are probably cached by your browser.

When you change and reload to test, try reloading using Ctrl+R to refresh the cache in that reload. This should work with all browsers.

Comment: Since you are reloading the page anyways, and since you don't need the dev tools open every time, I think the Ctrl+R method is much more useful and a better solution for your problem than disabling cache on dev tools everytime. That's at least the way I do it.

Comment: True! I did what sUP recomends but the problem of JS and CSS has arisen again. Maybe I did not do excatly how sUP instructed me. So there is still a chance that sUP's method works. But its true - for my case Ctrl+R is a better solution. It simply works. I was using it today all day long and had no trouble. Really thanks for giving me that simple little trick. Green check for your answer,amosmos, because in practice it really is more helpfull for me than sUP's (just that yesterday evening - when giving green check to sUP's method - I was not aware of that and was to tired to really test it).

Answer (score 7):

You can disable cache when developer tools is visible. 
Hit F12 and click the little gear at the bottom right. 
In "General" make sure that the first box "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" is ticked and you're good to go

Comment: I've tried it and is seems to work. I guess its a longterm solution. so I will put a green check to this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just in case other people come across this you can add a get variable to the file name like `src="js/custom.js?version=1"`  then it will recheck if it doesnt know.  You could have all the custom javascript and css files like this and with php use something like:

```
src="js/custom.js?version=<?php echo $version; ?>"
```

then justupdate `$version` in one place anytime you make a change.  This will also guarantee users see the change as well.